# Solving time-dependent Schrödinger equation using Lie algebra

Tags: schroedinger-equation, lie-algebra

I am trying to understand this chapter in order to solve the time-dependent Schrödinger equation by using [On the time-dependent solutions of the Schrödinger equation](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4020-5460-0_5) ([RG](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226282972_On_the_time-dependent_solutions_of_the_Schrodinger_equation)).

Example 1:

$$ i \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}=\left\{{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}}+E_{0}x \sin \omega t\right\}\psi \tag{1}$$

$$i\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{4} a_{i}H_{i} \right\} \psi \tag{2}$$

where $a_{1}=0$, $H_{1}=1$, $a_{2}=E_{0}\sin\omega t$, $H_2=x$, $a_{3}=0$, $H_{3}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, and $a_{4}=-\frac{1}{2}$, $H_{4}=\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}$.

Solving above equation will be equal to solving the the evolution operator.
$$i\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}=\dot{g_{1}}H_{1}U+\dot{g_{2}}H_{2}U+\dot{g_{3}}H_{3}U+\dot{g_{4}}H_{4}U \tag{3}$$

where $$\psi(x,t)=U(t)\psi(x,0) \tag{4}.$$

Now the next step was to find $g$s. For that purpose I started from $$\psi (x,t)=e^{g_{1}H_{1}+g_{2}H_{2}+g_{3}H_{3}+g_{4}H_{4}} \psi(x,0) \tag{5}$$
Taking derivative of $(5)$ w.r.t $t$ and then equating to equation $(1)$ as
$\dot{g_{1}}+\dot{g_{2}}x+\dot{g_3} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} +\dot{g_{4}}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+E_{0}x\sin \omega t$. By comparing the coefficients came to the conclusion that
$$i\dot{g_{4}}=-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$i\dot{g_{2}}=-E_{0}\sin \omega t$$
$$i\dot{g_{3}}=0$$
$$i\dot{g_{1}}=0$$
However, in the mentioned paper, $\dot{g_{3}}$ and $\dot{g_1}$ is not zero. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your evolution operator (3) is very-very wrong, since $H_3, H_4$ visibly fail to commute with *U*.  By contrast, your paper's (3) is right,
$$i\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}=i(\dot{g_{1}}H_{1}U+\dot{g_{2}}H_{2}U+ \dot{g_{3}}UH_{3} +\dot{g_{4}}UH_{4}) \tag{3}$$
$$= i(\dot{g_{1}}H_{1} +\dot{g_{2}}H_{2} + \dot{g_{3}}UH_{3} U^{-1}+\dot{g_{4}}UH_{4}U^{-1}) U\\
=i(\dot{g_{1}}H_{1} +\dot{g_{2}}H_{2} + \dot{g_{3}} e^{g_2x} \partial_x  e^{-g_2x}+\dot{g_{4}}e^{g_2x} \partial_x^2 e^{-g_2x}) U .$$

Needless to say, your starting point (5) is completely wrong. The correct starting point  as your reference stresses, is, instead,
$$ 
U(t)= e^{g_1} e^{g_2 x} e^{g_3 \partial_x} e^{g_4 \partial_x^2} .
$$

Can you take it from here to their correct (4)?

---

*NB on request*

Recall $$ \partial_x e^{-g_2 x}= e^{-g_2 x}(-g_2 +  \partial_x ),\implies\\
\partial_x^2 e^{-g_2 x}=  e^{-g_2 x}( g_2^2 -2g_2   \partial_x + \partial_x^2).   $$
The term linear in $\partial_x$ must vanish, yielding your source's
$$\dot g_3-2\dot g_4 g_2=0. \tag{4c}
$$

---

*NB on further request*

You must have made a mistake. Remember, cf (8), that the previous order of the *H*s has effectively been reversed. In explicit terms this second *U* effectively uses the order of the *inverse* of the previous one. So your analog of (3) is different, and you have, instead,
$$
\partial_t U= U\Bigl ( U^{-1}(\dot g_1 H_1 +\dot g _2 H_2 )U + \dot{g}_3 H_3+ \dot g_4 H_4 \Bigr ).
$$
They predictably assume that the reader has internalized the strategy and can easily deal with a transposition.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and guiding me to the right path. After following your steps, i took first and  second derivatives of $e^{-g_2 x}$ and then  comparing coefficients on both sides, i got 4(a), 4(b), and 4(d). I an still confused how to get number 4(c) on the paper. I really appreciate your help guiding me on this. I am new in this filed and never worked with evolution operator before.

Comment: Is not  $\partial _x^2 e^{-g_2 x} = g_2^2 e^{-g_2 x}-2g_2e^{-g_2 x} + 2e^{-g_2 x} \partial _x^2 $. After following the steps this is what I got $$ \partial _x^2 e^{-g_2 x} = \partial_x (\partial_x e^{-g_2 x}) = \partial_x(-g_2e^{-g_2 x} + e^{-g_2 x} \partial_x)$$
 $$ = \partial_x(-g_2 e^{-g_2 x} ) + \partial_x ( \partial_x(-g_2e^{-g_2 x} \partial_x)$$
$$ =  g_2^2 e^{-g_2 x}-g_2e^{-g_2 x} \partial_x + \partial_x(e^{-g_2 x}) \partial_x + e^{-g_2 x} \partial_x^2 $$

Comment: Can you refer a book/notes from where I can learn about this material?

Comment: No. Your evaluation is very wrong. Note  $\partial_x e^{-g_2 x}=e^{-g_2 x} (\partial_x -g_2)$  so that $\partial_x^2 e^{-g_2 x}=e^{-g_2 x} (\partial_x -g_2)^2$.

Comment: Yes, I got that part where $\partial_x e^{-g_2 x} =  e^{-g_2 x} (\partial_x -g_2) $ but still confused how you got  $\partial_x^2 e^{-g_2 x}= e^{-g_2 x} (\partial_x -g)^2$. Why there is no square for $e^{-g_2 x}$ term?

Comment: I Really don't understand what you are saying. You braid the gradient pst the exponential once, and then one more time. The operations are ***associative***,  so you may transpose parentheses arbitrarily: $AB=BC$, so $(A A)B= A(AB)=A(BC)=(AB)C=(BC)C=B(CC)$.

Comment: Ohh I see it now. Can you suggest a book/notes from where I can learn about this material?

Comment: just one more question, how you picked $U=e^{g_2 x}$ in the step where you first wrote  $U\partial_x U^{-1}$ and then replaced $U$ with $e^{g_2 x}$?

Comment: All the other factors commuted with the gradient, and eliminated themselves with their inverses. ***Only*** that factor failed to commute!

Comment: You might like [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.14401).

Comment: When you say $e^{g_2 x}$ does not commute with the gradient, do you mean that $$[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, e^{g_2 x} ] \neq 0 $$?
Also, using the same steps, I got 9a and 9c but not getting 9b and 9d. I again used $u=e^{g_2 x}$ to derive sets of equations in 9. Am I making any mistakes for deriving the sets of equations in 9?

Comment: Yes and Yes. That's what the commutation failure means. On your second issue, note your exponential factors are in almost the reverse order, so make sure you derive the proper (3) analog!! It is easiest if you just write the  explicit *H*s in the exponentials, and see what everything implies...

Comment: What if we have $x^2$ and $x^4$ term in eq(1). We can write then $a_5$, $a_6$, $H_5$, $H_6$ etc parts? and repeat the steps? IF yes then how to modify the corresponding unitary transformation?

Comment: I would highly appreciate any recommendation about Lie algebra basics for time-dependent Hamiltonians.

Comment: Yes, but I would insert the new factors in *U* and the new Hs close to $H_2=x$, since they commute with it. Sorry, this PDE method is very very common, and it is parochial to associate it with just the TDSE. I don't know of any books, but there should be several. The authors of yoru cited reference appear parochial and believe they are inventing something new, but they are wrong. Look at citations to them and references therein in google scholar....

Comment: I assume you hav gone through the references of your paper and especially [8], Rau & Unnikrishnan, *PhysLett*  **A 222**. 304 (1996) and refs thereto in Google Scholar, such as    Lohe (2009)  *J Phys* A: Math. Theor. *42* 035307, of course.

Comment: For $H=-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}+[\frac{1}{2}-{x_{0}}^{2}\frac{t}{T}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{t}{T}]x^2+\frac{t}{T}x^{4}+\frac{t}{T} {x_{0}}^{2}$, can I use $U(t)=e^{g_1}e^{g_2 x}e^{g_3 x^2}e^{g_4 x^3}e^{g_5 x^4}e^{g_6 \partial_x}e^{g_7 {\partial_x}^2}$?

Comment: Looks right, but I can't be supervising your whole project. Good luck...